# Relative file paths versus explicit file paths and different test runners causing tests to fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit, filepath, testdriven.net

I have some unit tests that I wrote using NUnit and to get things going, I had originally used my local file paths for the files I load in for the tests, written out explicitly.  All the tests passed with flying colors after they were all finished.  Then, to push to the main repo, I changed the paths to relative paths.  Now the tests fail both locally and on the main repo.  A DLL that never had any trouble being loaded in with an explicitly written file paths is now unable to be loaded, yet the paths are the same as before.  Can anyone think of why relative paths as a string instead of an explicit file path being used would make a difference as to whether a certain DLL can be found or not?  Thanks!

### Update

I have played around with running the tests using TestDriven and Visual Studio's test runner and Test Driven does allow the tests to run.  The relative paths don't seem to give it too much trouble.  It is when I use Visual Studio's test runner that I run into issues.  Could the DLL's not being found be in a different location based on the test runner I use?

Comment: Could you post the code that's actually failing?  It's difficult to diagnose the problem without that.

Comment: It's pretty specific.  But it is failing on a line that is a setter for a particular control.  Through some updating processes, certain gui controls are being updated, even though my tests don't have a gui that comes up.  The DLL that is unable to load at this particular line is the Kitware.VTK.dll.  So it is frustrating that this is causing an issue for graphics that I'm not actually using in the test.  And to refactor out the graphics out would be ideal, but this would also involve months of work that we just don't have time to do in order for MY tests to succeed.

Comment: That's still not much to go on.  What do the file paths in question point to?  I was thinking you might be loading assemblies by path but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: I'm taking an encrypted xml file used to build out another file and perform some operations on this file.  The original file lives in another projects _UnitTests/_Data/ directory (this project is in the same solution as my Tests project).  The DLL that can't be loaded is in the bin directory of multiple projects.  Also, thanks for continuing to pursue helping me on this.  I really appreciate it.